# T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) solve this recurrence using iterative method

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

How to solve the recurrence equation

T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4)

For base case T(n)=1

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214886/solving-the-recurrence-tn-tn-2-tn-4-tn-8) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907262/how-to-solve-the-recurrence-equation-tn-tn-2tn-4-thetan) for clue but it didn't help me solving it using iterative method

I just need to get to the general equation for this.

Comment: What is unclear with those? You iterate and plug `n/2` and `n/4` for `n`. Such as `T(n) = [T(n/4) + T(n/8)]+ [T(n/8) + T(n/16)]`... Keep going...

Comment: I already tried it, went upto T(n)=T(n/4)+2T(n/16)+3T(n/32)+T(n/64).
But I could not get to the generic equation @cricket_007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how to use the "iterative method" to solve this.

But there's a similarity between the recurrence relation you have and the that for the fibonacci numbers, and that can be used to find a solution.

T(2^k) = T(2^(k-1)) + T(2^(k-2)). So assuming T(1) = T(2) = 1, T(2^k) = Fib(k). So for n a power of 2, T(n) = Fib(lg(n)). Since Fib(n) = Theta(phi^n), T(n) = Theta(phi^(lg n)) = Theta(n ^ lg(phi)) ~= n^0.7

Here Fib(n) is the n'th Fibonacci number, and phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2.

Comment: Apreciate it.Why did you

Comment: Appreciate it, but why did you take T(2^k) instead of T(n)?

Comment: @infinityAssault because powers of two produce exact Fibonacci numbers. It's common in many recurrence relation solutions involving /2 (for example that for merge sort or binary search) since rounding effects make the solutions difficult if you don't.

Comment: This is also given in the question "For solving Fibonacci the formula is Fn=  1/√5 (ϕn− (−ϕ)−n) and you can ignore the constants in this formula" but I did not get it how to use it

Comment: formula for Fib(n) = Theta(phi^n). where did this Theta came from?
Or how to go from Theta(n^log(phi)) = Theta ( n^0.2) to n^0.7 as you wrote in the answer above? @PaulHankin